# How to call an API even adBlocker is enabled in React?

Tags: reactjs

I am using detectAdBlock library to detect ad-blocks.
Based on the response,I am calling a checkin API.
That API gives a boolean if user visits the page for the first time, it returns true.

When the response is true, I have created a profile popup modal which only appears when the Check-in API response is true.Currently I have a logic like if ad-blocker is enabled, I am not calling that API.When the user disables the ad-block, then only the API was getting called.

Now I have added a close button on my Ad-Block popup and because of that the user can turn off the ad-block popup but are not able to see the profile Popup because the check-In API doesn't get called because the ad-blocker library response is still true.
[image]

Here is the code -->

```
Main.js

componentDidMount() {
  detectAnyAdblocker().then((detected) => {
      if (!detected) {
        this.props.checkInAPI(params).then((resp) => {
          localStorage.setItem('firstTimeUserVisit', resp && resp.data === true);
          const userId = localStorage.getItem('userId');
        });
      }
    });

}

render() {
return (
  <AdBlock />

)
}

Profile.js (Popup condition)
  const firstTimeCheckIn = localStorage.getItem('firstTimeUserVisit');
 if (firstTimeCheckIn === 'true' && !adBlock) {
        setShowProfilePopup(true);
      } 

return (
{showProfilePopup && (<PopupModal> ..... </PopupModal>)}
)

AdBlock.js 

let closeAdBlock = false;

const AdBlock = ({ eventData }) => {
  const [adBlock, setAdBlock] = useState(false);

  const onCloseAdBlock = () => {
    setAdBlock(false);
    closeAdBlock = true;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!closeAdBlock) {
      detectAnyAdblocker().then((detected) => {
        if (detected) {
          setAdBlock(true);
        }
      });
    }
  }, [adBlock]);
return (
 <PopupModal
          id="adblock-popup"
          custClassName={'adblock-popups'}
          onCloseFunc={() => onCloseAdBlock()}
          showModal={adBlock}
>.....</PopupModal>
)
```

I want the API should be called whether a user has ad-block enabled or disabled but the profile popup should also be shown if user visits the page for the first time

Comment: You should decouple the logic for checking the first visit and the adblock

Comment: Can you please explain more